# Access application in cluster via node IP address connection refuse

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, k3s, traefik-ingress

(The final goal of what I am doing is to access my application via node IP address)

My cluster is using Traefik ingress controller.
The Ingress rule is:

```
      kind: Ingress
      ...
      ...
      spec:
        rules:
          - host: my.app
            http:
              paths:
                - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
                  path: /
                  backend:
                    service:
                      name: my-app-svc
                      port:
                        number: 3000
```

There is also a `LoadBalancer` service deployed:

```
k get svc -n kube-system traefik
NAME      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
traefik   LoadBalancer   10.43.58.233   192.168.10.82   80:32003/TCP,443:30554/TCP   40d
```

As you can see the external IP is `192.168.10.82` for this `LoadBalancer` service.

On my laptop, I map that external IP with the hostname in `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.10.82 my.app
```

I can successfully access my deployed application via the external IP: http://my.app

**Now, I would like to access it via IP address instead.**
This is what I try to do below:
[image]

So, I have deployed a `NodePort` service for the controller:

```
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Service
      metadata:
        name: traefik-node-port-svc
        namespace: kube-system
      spec:
        type: NodePort
        ports:
        - name: http
          port: 80
          targetPort: 80
          nodePort: 30182
          protocol: TCP
        - name: https
          port: 443
          targetPort: 443
          nodePort: 30183
          protocol: TCP
        selector:
          app: traefik
```

I can see this `NodePort` service is deployed:

```
NAME                    TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
traefik-node-port-svc   NodePort   10.43.148.128   <none>        80:30182/TCP,443:30183/TCP   69m
```

As you can see above, the exposed port for HTTP traffic is `30182`.

Then, I get the node (I have only one node):

```
k get node -o wide
NAME        STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION        INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE              KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
testk3s01   Ready    control-plane,master   40d   v1.21.5+k3s2   192.168.10.82   <none>        k3OS v0.21.5-k3s2r1   5.4.0-88-generic   containerd://1.4.11-k3s1
```

I can see above that the node's internal IP is `192.168.10.82`.

I then try to access my application via `<node internal IP>:<NodePort svc exposed port>`

```
> curl 192.168.10.82:30182
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.10.82 port 30182 after 7 ms: Connection refused
```

But connection is refused, why is that? How can I access my application via IP address directly?

The `NodePort` service detail is like following:

```
> kubectl describe svc traefik-node-port-svc -n kube-system
Name:                     traefik-node-port-svc
Namespace:                kube-system
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=traefik
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.43.148.128
IPs:                      10.43.148.128
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30182/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  30183/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

**==== Update based on @Sibtain's answer ====**

I tried the option 2 of @Sibtain's answer to figure out the correct `targetPort` for my `NodePort` service.

I first try to find the `targetPort` from that `LoadBalancer` service:

```
> kubectl get svc traefik -o yaml -n kube-system

...
...
ports:
  - name: web
    nodePort: 32003
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: web
  - name: websecure
    nodePort: 30554
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: websecure
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik
    app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

As you can see above, the `targetPort` which points to the application pod is `80` for http & `443` https respectively. I can also see the `Selector` section used by this service.

So, I updated my `NodePort` Service manifest to point to the same `targetPort`:

```
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Service
      metadata:
        name: traefik-node-port-svc
        namespace: kube-system
      spec:
        type: NodePort
        ports:
        - name: web
          port: 80
          targetPort: web
          nodePort: 30182
          protocol: TCP
        - name: websecure
          port: 443
          targetPort: websecure
          nodePort: 30183
          protocol: TCP
        selector:
          app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
          app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik
```

I re-deployed this `NodePort` Service. But when check again, it still has `<none>` endpoint:

```
> kubectl describe svc traefik-node-port-svc -n kube-system
Name:                     traefik-node-port-svc
Namespace:                kube-system
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/instance=traefik,app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik,app=traefik
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.43.148.128
IPs:                      10.43.148.128
Port:                     web  80/TCP
TargetPort:               web/TCP
NodePort:                 web  30182/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Port:                     websecure  443/TCP
TargetPort:               websecure/TCP
NodePort:                 websecure  30183/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Now all the services under the `kube-system` shows me this:

```
kubectl get svc -n kube-system
NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
kube-dns                ClusterIP      10.43.0.10      <none>          53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       41d
metrics-server          ClusterIP      10.43.111.166   <none>          443/TCP                      41d
traefik                 LoadBalancer   10.43.58.233    192.168.10.82   80:32003/TCP,443:30554/TCP   40d
traefik-node-port-svc   NodePort       10.43.148.128   <none>          80:30182/TCP,443:30183/TCP   19h
```

The curl result:

```
> curl 192.168.10.82:30182
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.10.82 port 30182 after 10 ms: Connection refused

> curl 192.168.10.82:80
404 page not found

> curl 192.168.10.82:30183
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.10.82 port 30183 after 860 ms: Connection refused

> curl 192.168.10.82:443
404 page not found
```

Comment: does `curl 127.0.0.1:30182` work on the node?

Comment: How to get into the node & verify that? @Sibtain  Could you please provide more detail so that I can try.

Comment: I ssh to the machine where the cluster is running, tried `curl 127.0.0.1:30182`, get `Connection refused`

Comment: Try `curl 10.43.148.128` as well. also share the output of `kubectl describe svc traefik-node-port-svc` in your question. You should also double-check `targetPort: 80`, this (80) should be the port on which your traefik pod should be running.

Comment: @Sibtain , I updated my post with the service details.  The `curl 10.43.148.128` is also a refuse connection error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Service `traefik-node-port-svc` has no `Endpoints` attached to it (note the `<none>` in `describe` output)

This means there are no pods that the service can redirect the request to. Most likely you have an incorrect `TargetPort` or the `selector` label (`app: traefik`) is wrong.

To fix the `targetPort` you can opt any of the two options below:

1. Run the `kubectl describe pod <traefik-pod-here>` and note down the
   `port`. That should be the `targetPort` in `traefik-node-port-svc`
   specification.
2. Run `kubectl describe svc traefik -n kube-system` and note the
   `targetPort` from there as you have an already running LoadBalancer
   Service so it means that it is redirecting the request to the
   appropriate pods.

If the issue is with the `selector` label, you can check the labels by running `kubectl get pod <traefik-pod-here> --show-labels` and add the appropriate labels.

**EDIT**

The easier way to create a Service and make sure you get the labels right is to use the declarative [`kubectl expose`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#expose) command, assuming that the traefik pod is running as a Deployment named `traefik` on port `9000`, the command would look something like: (*Note: the actual nodePort would be allocated automatically from the range 30000-32767*)

```
kubectl expose deployment traefik --name=traefik-node-port-svc --type=NodePort --port=80 --target-port=8000
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! I found the traefik pod, the port there is `Ports:         9000/TCP, 8000/TCP, 8443/TCP`, which one should I use for `targetPort`?

Comment: The labels of the traefik pod from the command you mentioned is `app.kubernetes.io/instance=traefik,app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik,helm.sh/chart=traefik-9.18.2,pod-template-hash=97b44b794` , so, in the `NodePort` service manifest, what label should I use? Could you please update your answer with that?

Comment: When I try the 2nd option in your answer to get the `targetPort` of the LoadBalancer Service by `kubectl describe svc traefik -n kube-system`, it gives me `TargetPort:  websecure/TCP`, there is no port number there.

Comment: `TargetPort:  websecure/TCP` this looks like the name of the port on to which the pod is listening. But to be safe try running `kubectl get svc traefik -o yaml -n kube-system` and see the `specs.ports` section and use that in your NodePort Service (might only need to check port and targetPort)

Comment: Checkout my updated answer if you are having issues matching the labels, but I would recommend to try to fix the `targetPort` issue first.

Comment: I updated my post for what I have tried based on your answer. It still have the `<none>` endpoint issue even I updated the `targetPort` of my `NodePort` service. Could you please take a look in my post above? Thanks.

Comment: I see that you have updated the `selectors`, try updating the `targetPort: 80` to `targetPort: web` and then redeploy

Comment: I did that, result is the same. Please check my latest update in my post. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252712/discussion-between-sibtain-and-user842225).